What exactly does the while loop do here in insertion sort?


const arr = [8, 20, -2, 4, -6];
insertionSort(arr);
console.log(arr); // [-6, -2, 4, 8, 20]


function insertionSort(arr) {
  // Two loops, outer to look at each element, and inner to shift elements

  // Outer loop
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) // i starts at 1 because we don't need to sort the first element
  {
    let key = arr[i];
    let j = i - 1;

    // Inner loop
    while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
      arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
      j--;
    }
    arr[j + 1] = key;
  }
}



It's working fine I just don't understand it and I can implement it all on my own except for the while loop. I'm a beginner so please bear with me

j>=0 is the exit clause so it's not an infinite loop.   arr[j] > key keeps it looping "while" the value is less than the current arr[i] (key).   arr[j+1]=arr[j] swaps the current indexed item with the next one - essentially moving values that are larger than the current ([i]) value up the array.   j-- points to the previous value.   The relevant part is outside the while arr[j+1]=key which swaps the key (arr[i]) with the first value below it that is not larger.  (probably make more sense with >= otherwise it just swaps same-values but I've not looked that closely)

@fdomn-m I think I understand now, thanks! But what do you mean probably makes more sense with >= ? I followed a tutorial by a guy who did it in C so I did the same in JavaScript. Would that make a difference?

i starts at 1 because we don't need to sort the first element - that's not strictly true, you do need to sort the first element - just there's nothing before the first element to swap with

@fdomn-m So do I change it to sort the first element? I watched many videos about Insertion sort including CS50x, and they all said the first element is assumed to be sorted. Could you clarify more please?

One approach to understanding what code does is "dry-run" it - you can use paper if it helps.  But put values in and step the code "offline" (dry-run, not to be confused with DRY).  In this case, imagine an array of [1,2,1] and step through i and step through the while.   Like I said, it was only a first impression that it might be better as >=, it's equally probably not the case.

"So do I change it to sort the first element" - so you don't understand what the while loop does.   There's no action on the first element as the action is in the while loop which looks at previous elements.   If you have array [3,2,1] it will end up as [1,2,3] - the first element "3" clearly gets "sorted".   "assume it's already sorted" means if you have an array [3] then there's nothing to sort at that time.  Because the ode looks at previous elements and there aren't any previous elements of the first element.

You don't need to sort the first element when looking at the first element, so it can be skipped.  The code is correct, I was pointing out the "don't need to sort the first element" which is clearly wrong / badly worded.

There is a lot of information about sorting algorithms, such as "insertion sort". Google it to find the progress visualization on YouTube.

It may help to distinguish two partitions in the array:

The left side partition that is already sorted
The right side partition that is not (necessarily) sorted.

At the start of an outer iteration, the value of i represents the index at which the second partition starts. It can start at 1, because that means the left partition has just one value, and a list with just one value is sorted (obviously).
Each iteration of the outer loop grows the sorted partition with one element, and shrinks the other partition by one. This continues until the sorted partition has all elements of the array (and the right-side partition is empty).
Before the inner loop starts, we can assume the left partition has grown to include the element at index i, i.e. key, but this value may not be at the right position in that sorted partition, and that is what the inner loop will fix:
The goal of the inner loop is to find the right spot in the sorted partition for the key value that currently might sit at the wrong position. While looking for that spot, it also moves the values it encounters one place to the right. In so doing it foresees an insertion spot where key can be written to.
When the inner loop ends, j + 1 is the index where key belongs within the (grown) sorted partition.
Example
Let's say we have already made some iterations of the outer loop, and start a new iteration with i equal to 5, and have this state of the array:
     sorted     |   unsorted
                |
[2, 5, 8, 12, 15, 7, 1, 11, 6]
                | ↑
                | i=5

Then the following happens:
The value at index i is saved in the variable key, and that index is now considered an empty slot (it is not really emptied, but it helps to see it that way):
      sorted        |  unsorted
                    |
[2, 5, 8, 12, 15, --, 1, 11, 6]
               ↑    |
               j    | key: 7 (must be inserted in sorted partition)

The inner loop starts at j=4 and walks back moving values one position to their right (into the "gap") for as long as necessary. After a few iterations we get:
      sorted        |  unsorted
                    |
[2, 5, --, 8, 12, 15, 1, 11, 6]
    ↑               |
    j               | key: 7 (must be inserted in sorted partition)

At this point it is the first time we encounter a value at index j that is less than key, and so that loop exits. The gap is now at index j+1, and that is where the value key belongs.
      sorted       |  unsorted
                   |
[2, 5, 7, 8, 12, 15, 1, 11, 6]
    ↑              | 
    j              |

I hope this clarifies it.
